# Wordpress - How to allow direct links to files in subfolders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress installation at root of site.

```
www.site.com
```

If i upload for example an mp3 to `

```
www.site.com/music/123.mp3`
```

i cannot directly link to the mp3 to download.

How can i enable direct links to a certain subfolder?

Do i just need to modify the .htaccess file? Is there a plugin or a certain folder that allows this?

It works fine if my wordpress is installed `

```
www.site.com/blog`
```

Thanks

Comment: In my WordPress test bench, I'm able to access http://localhost/music/123.mp3 just fine, even with permalinks on. What is your permalink setting set to? And maybe share your .htaccess. And is there an .htaccess in your /music directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your functions.php file in your theme, or in a plugin.

```
function my_custom_htaccess( $rules ){

// Create our condition.
$exclude_cond = PHP_EOL . 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(music/.*)$';

// Look for a place to insert it.
// We are going to put this just after the RewriteBase line.
// This is not in the same place as all the other RewriteCond statements,
// But it seems to work.
$search = '/RewriteBase.+/';

// Replace w/ found string, plus condition
$replace = '$0' . $exclude_cond;

// Rock and roll.
$rules = preg_replace($search, $replace, $rules);

return $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_custom_htaccess');
```

After adding it somewhere, go to your WordPress Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and just click save changes (this will flush your rewrite rules).